Can you run Chai tests using Mocha for ES6 modules?
I am trying to run an API test for getting the version using Chai. I have this test in src/tests/version.tests.js. I am using mocha ./src/tests/**/*.tests.js to run it.
For some reason I get this error when running the command above:
Exception during run: version.tests.js:1
import chai, { expect } from "chai";
       ^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'chai' does not provide an export named 'default'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:132:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:214:5)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:430:15)
    at async formattedImport (node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:9:14)       
    at async exports.requireOrImport (node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:42:28)
    at async exports.loadFilesAsync (node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:100:20)
    at async singleRun (node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:125:3)
    at async exports.handler (node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:370:5)

My version.tests.js file looks like this:
import chai, { expect } from "chai";
import chaiHttp from "chai-http";
import app from "../app.js";

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Version API', () => {
    it('should return the correct version', async () => {
        try {
            const res = await chai.request(app).get('/api/version');
            
            expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    });
});

The packages' versions are:
    "chai": "^5.1.1",
    "chai-http": "^4.4.0",
    "mocha": "^10.4.0"

Why is this happening?

have you tried a different version of chai?

chai indeed doesn't have a default export. If you want to use use, import { use } ... or import * as chai .... That's nothing to do with Mocha.

@jonrsharpe yes, that indeed works, thanks!

Chai 5 cannot be imported as a default as it does not have default export. You can use chai 5.1 and chai-http 5.1 as below in your test files.
import { expect, use } from 'chai';
import { default as chaiHttp, request } from 'chai-http';

use(chaiHttp);

// execute method will take express app as input and returns ChaiHttp.Agent
req = request.execute(expressApp);


// Use req object to request API calls on app
req.get('/')

If you are using commonJS for your project and haven't specified package.json type as module, then you will have to write test cases in .mjs files.
